# Merge sort application

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, mergesort

I'm doing an exercise where given an array of N values, I need to get the two numbers that their subtraction (the highest - the lowest) is the most positive number. I want v to be larger than c... the case is that... let's say I want to buy auctions at price C so I can sell them at price V and get the maximum profit, and each cell of the array is the price of that auction at day t, so I want to buy at the lowest price possible so I can sell at the highest price possible so C must appear before V in the array. For example:

```
n = 8
arr = {6,7,3,8,9,2,1,4,20}
```

I want `c = 1` and `v = 20`, because `20 - 1 = 19` (it means the subtraction from this 2 numbers is the highest)

Another example:

```
n = 6
arr = {8,12,45,40,18,29}
```

I want `c = 8` and `v = 45` because their subtraction is the highest number of all the other subtractions. (I want to clarify that c is not always the smallest number in the array). BOTH NUMBERS DO NOT NEED TO BE NEXT TO EACH OTHER. If I have `n = 1, {1}` then `c = 1` and `v = 1`.

This example demonstrates c and v are not always the lowest/highest values.

```
n = 6
arr = {19,27,5,6,7,8}
```

In this case `c = 19` and `v = 27`

Also, I need to solve this using merge sort's code many (examples divide it by two methods: *mergesort* which handles the recursions, and *merge* that does the change of positions using an aux array).

I'm using mergesort code(merge is unnecessary in my opinion because I don't care about sorting), so far I have the following code, but it is obviously wrong, could someone tell me what I'm not doing right?

```
public static void mergeSort(int start, int end) {
    if(start < end) {
        int half = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(start, half);
        for(int i = start; start < half; start++, i++){
            if((arr[i+1] - arr[i]) > temp){
                temp = arr[i+1] - arr[i];
                c = i;
                v = i+1;
            }
        }
        mergeSort(half+1, end);
        for(int i = half+1; i < end; half++, i++){
            if((arr[i+1] - arr[i]) > temp){
                temp = arr[i+1] - arr[i];
                c = i;
                v = i+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: hi, in second example - why not 8 and 45?

Comment: @Simeon there was an homework tag here, someone removed it

Comment: you cant invent variables on the go!!@!@!@!@! temp is undefined and so is arr...

Comment: @Simeon Yes it is my homework, I'm having trouble with the recursion part. I already figure it out in O(n^2) but I need it to be O(nlogn)

Comment: why dont you care about sorting ? it seems what you need is the lowest number and the highest number. basically, ordering the array you need array[ n - 1 ] - array[ 0 ]. no ?

Comment: @fingerman You were right about second example, thanks, I only pasted the method, arr and temp are global.

Comment: @Diogo My examples were not good enough :S but in this exercise the lowest and the highest are not always the good choice, the numbers are decided by their difference.

Comment: @Ignacio: can you give an example when max{arr} - min{arr} won't do the job please?

Comment: So, `c` must come before `v` in the array.

Comment: I do not see what this has to do with sorting or merging.

Comment: @Svante Yes! and... I need to use mergesort coding so I get my answer as closest to an algorithm of O(nlogn) plus the teacher told us "to modify merge sort and use it."

Comment: @Ignacio: do you HAVE TO do it with modified mergesort? I'm pretty sure I got a O(n) solution for it (it works for all of your examples, I'm trying to make sure if it is good for all cases as well)

Comment: The exercise asks for a O(nlogn) solution; the teacher told us to reuse merge sort.

Comment: O(n) is O(nlogn) because for every n>N (for a constant N), there is a constant c such that c*n < nlogn, so the O(n) solution applies here, however, it doesn't apply the 'reuse merge sort' part:\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the name `mergeSort` in your code is inherited....

As you have already do the recursion, there is no need to iterate through all the elements, because **after** recursion, the result is already presented. For example, one possible way is to swap the minimum to the first place and the maximum to the last place, and later, on the "upper" level of recursion you can just retrieve them directly.

---

Here is another solution which takes advantage of the philosophy of merge-sort, but only **returns** max.

```
public class test {
    static int arr [] = {6,7,3,8,9,2,1,4,20};

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println(merge_select_max(0, arr.length - 1));
    }

    public static int merge_select_max (int start, int end) { // both inclusive
        if (start == end) {
            return arr[start];          
        }
        else {
            int half = (start + end) / 2;
            int first = merge_select_max (start, half);
            int second = merge_select_max (half + 1, end);
            return (first > second ? first : second);           
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: is it just me or this is c++ and not java? also won't compile in c++: (`return result(arr[start], arr[start];`) (missing ')')

Comment: haven't read your answer in length, but if this guy is still studying java, don't complicate him with OOP and stuff

Comment: @Dante this method returns the highest value right in a given array, right? what I'd still need two things, 1) the lowest value (which can be easily done with your given code) and 2) that the subtraction between these two is the highest number in comparison with the subtraction between the other numbers. Any ideas of how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Ignacio Pochart, 2 ways. 1) Use `Dimension` which can store 2 `public` `int`, and thus you can return the whole result (one `int` for max, and one `int` for min). (If you can understand a little C++, you can refer to the edit history of this answer.) 2) When doing the recursion, swap min to the first place of the sub array, and max to the last place, but this will **change** the original order of the array, if you do not make a copy.

Comment: @Ignacio Pochart, I recommend 2) as you can do more coding yourself. XD